# How to create cross-platform Internet shortcut files

Tags: shortcuts

Is there any way to create Internet shortcut files that will work with all operating systems (including Mac, Windows, and Linux)? I often switch between Windows and Linux, and I haven't yet found a way to create an internet shortcut file (on the desktop or in a local folder) that is compatible with all operating systems.

Comment: 2018 update: macs can handle .url files, though they default to Safari. Linux and Android do not handle .url. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webcuts/kehckhdcknjaadegmihldoedmdfmpcmk can make xplatform links for you.

Comment: [Quite related question here](https://superuser.com/q/277186/910769), also proposing [html-refresh](https://superuser.com/a/1340296/910769), as well as some bash scripts, which can be used in windows with a powershell, [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/), [WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) or [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/)/[MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/). `.desktop`-Files might not fit as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found a reasonable cross-platform solution. This HTML document could be used as a shortcut to stackoverflow.com, and it would immediately redirect to that site when opened from the desktop:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; //change this to the URL
                                                       //you want to redirect to
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is such a fantastically simple solution... thank you

Comment: Why not use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">` in the `<head>` instead of relying on javascript?

Comment: While most browsers will accept that bare-minimum oneliner `.html file`, @Evan or the reader can consider [this more exhaustive answer](https://superuser.com/a/1031155/910769). [My answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1682615/910769), where I provide a script that automatically generates `.html`-Files like this, builds upon that.

Comment: Note that the file extension must be `.html` for this to work.

Answer (score 20):

Credit to [Evan Mattson from the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/538089/how-to-create-cross-platform-internet-shortcut-files/1031155#comment1059077_538093).

From [W3C, Technique H76: Using meta refresh to create an instant client-side redirect](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html):

> The objective of this technique is to enable redirects on the client side without confusing the user. Redirects are preferably implemented on the server side (see [SVR1: Implementing automatic redirects on the server side instead of on the client side](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/SVR1) (SERVER) ), but authors do not always have control over server-side technologies.

Example from the link above:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
  <head>      
    <title>The Tudors</title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://thetudors.example.com/'" />    
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <p>This page has moved to a <a href="http://thetudors.example.com/">
      theTudors.example.com</a>.</p> 
  </body>  
</html>
```

Basically, a refresh is done after zero seconds (immediately) to the specified URL, before the page content is loaded, and without JavaScript.

Comment: You can consider [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1682615/910769), where I provide a script that automatically generates `.html`-Files like this.

Comment: You can also consider/compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1340296/910769)

Answer (score 18):

You can define a file named as following - `MyInternetShortcut.url`.

It's content should be:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://my.amazingsite.com/
```

This works on Windows and macOS.

Comment: Maybe your Linux. Opens in text editor on my Linux Mint 17.3 Mate system.

Comment: I have Linux Mint 18.3 and it doesn't work as well. I guess my memory tricked me. It does work on macOS and Windows. I will update the answer. Thank You.

Comment: Works well on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: It does work well with many (graphical, modern) Linux distros - and if not, most usual browsers can intrepret it, so you can open the `xyz.url` with it. I wrote [a script provided here](https://superuser.com/a/1682971/910769) that automatically generates url-links like proposed by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use, I wrote a script to generate `.url`-files like [Royi suggested in his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1404213/910769). Making this script runnable with e.g. `chmod +x url_linkscript.sh` makes things even more handy. This file contains:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "[InternetShortcut]
URL=$1" > "$2"
```

You can then run it like this: `$ url_linkscript.sh "https://my.amazingsite.com/" "result.url"`. (*Depending on your link and file name, this usually also works without the quotes <kbd>"</kbd>.*)

Comment: This answer could be extended by a `.bat`-script that does the same thing from within windows (without the need for a bash compatibility layer).